# Error while migrating TF state files from local to S3 backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have few services where the Terraform remote state files exists in local, now we are migrating them to S3 backend, while most of the services had no issues, but one of the service is throwing some error, I am unable to find the root cause for it and also did not get much help online. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
Error: Error migrating the workspace "preprod-main" from the previous "local" backend
to the newly configured "s3" backend:
    Error copying state from the previous "local" backend to the newly configured 
"s3" backend:
    cannot import state with serial 7 over newer state with serial 8
```

Comment: Some hints here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25761

Comment: Are you sure - the state is not already there in S3 (like from previous attempt)?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that in your S3 bucket, at the location you are trying to copy the local state to, there already exists a state file.

Open the S3 console, browse to the location in the bucket where you want to put the state for `preprod-main` and check what's there.

It seems the state that is already there is newer than your local one, so be careful with deleting the state in S3.

Comment: Yes it was the case Casey, there were already TF state files present, and I was not aware where to look at. Thank you though for pointing.